# При отображении вьюхи в браузере выскакивает ошибка

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: Ошибка]

Сгенерировал новое приложение в консоли командой `rails new stukdo`, потом сгенерировал контроллер и вьюху `rails generate controller pages home`, потом открываю эту вьюху, в html редакторе пишу `HELLO WORLD`, запускаю сервер - и вот оно ругается на эти 2 строчки. Я их просто удалил и оно вроде как то отображается. Можно ли их удалять? Что спровоцировало эту ошибку? Как ее правильно устранять? Если что, работаю под операционной системой windows, диктор скринкастов делает на MacOS

Comment: А какой у вас там JS'овый рантайм? Встроенный в Windows MWSH? Или вы что-то отдельно устанавливали, вроде `therubyracer` или Node.js? И было бы интересно посмотреть на трейсы. И постарайтесь существенную для вопроса информацию прикладывать текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: Но вообще правильно вам говорят, разработка под Rails на Windows это хождение по минному полю без миноискателя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, замени 'application' на 'default' и получишь свой "Hello World". Но, в будущем, когда будешь писать серьезное веб-приложение, обязательно будешь использовать css/js и это будет проблемой, поскольку, например css представлен в рельсах через scss, который в свою очередь компилируется. И Windows с этой задачей не справляется. Эти две строчки формируют тег link, который подключает css/js файлы на страницу. Устанавливай VirtualBox и Ubuntu. Писать на рельсах из под Windows плохая идея.

Comment: Что значит не справляется?